# How to handle a 401 unauthorized response with Backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I configure my Backbone router with different views. But on some views, I need to fetch a collection. If the user is not logged in, server returns a 401 http status.

So, I configure jQuery's global ajax settings like that:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error ajax");
        if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
            console.log('error 401');
            app.router.navigate('', { trigger: true });
        }
    }
});
```

But it never goes in the error callback, even if the response code is 401.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying the ajax options globally, I modified `Backbone.sync` function to handle authentication.

```
Backbone.sync = (function(syncFn) {
    return function(method, model, options) {
        options = options || {};

        var beforeSend = options.beforeSend,
            error = options.error;

        // Add headers
        options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('withCredentials', true);
            if (beforeSend) return beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
        };

        // handle unauthorized error (401)
        options.error = function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error sync");
            if (error) error.call(options.context, xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
            if (xhr.status === 401) {
                console.log('error 401');
                app.router.navigate('', { trigger: true });
            }
        };

        return syncFn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(Backbone.sync);
```